# Poor project description for bachelor thesis (student-exchange)

Tags: thesis, bachelor, abroad, student-exchange

I'm going to do my bachelor thesis abroad this fall. I'm supposed to find a supervisor both at my home university and at the exchange university. I already found two professors willing to supervise me and got an interesting topic for the thesis.

Now the supervisor back here at my home university wants a short abstract explaining the content of the work I'm supposed to do when abroad in fall. The professor of the other university (well known in the field) has been very helpful so far and asked his PHD student to write a project description.

I feel like the professor didn't look at the description and just forwarded it to me from his PHD. I'm reluctant to send it to my supervisor here at my home university as I don't think he will be satisfied with it. I'm unsure what to do now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would show it to him along with your caveats. Ask for help from him but also offer your own suggestions about what might be "extracted" from the statement. Once you have some local agreement, send it back to the "foreign" prof as a suggestion.

Make it a negotiation, but first get some help and buy in from the prof you know best. Don't treat it as a "done deal" initially. Your local advisor can probably help a lot.

The bad English and bad formatting should be ignored. The imprecision is more concerning, but you can probably work around that. Especially if it is obviously too much to do in the time available.

I'll guess that the doctoral student at the other end was shocked and dismayed to have been given the task.

Comment: This seems like a good idea. I will get in touch with my local advisor tomorrow. But could you please explain why you think the doctoral student was dismayed? Here at my university it's common practice that the PHD does most of the supervision of the bachelor sudents.

Comment: Because of the poor job in writing it. It seems to indicate a lack of practice, so maybe unusual there.